# Issue with Cloudinary in reading and uploading image from binary or base64 string

Tags: base64, cloudinary

I am trying to upload and image to cloudinary by passing binary data of an image or base64 string. when i try to pass a base64 string as a data uri I am getting a error with the response of status code 502. but it works fine with small base64 strings.

This works fine

```
 res = cloudinary.uploader.upload("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==")
```

whereas when I pass some lengthy string it fails with 502 status code.
Might be because the uri cannot handle large value. Is there any other right way for passing lengthy strings?

or how can i pass a binary data as a input to the cloudinary?

Comment: Please can you update this with the outcome of your communication with Cloudinary?

Answer (score 1):

I'm Itay from Cloudinary.

In order to understand this issue better we'll need to take a deeper look at your account. We'll need some more information like your cloud name, timestamp of the fault uploads and more.
If you prefer this to be handled more privately, you're more than welcomed to open a support ticket (http://support.cloudinary.com/tickets/new) and we'll be happy to assist.

Comment: I'm trying to parse a bit string into the cloudinary.uploader, but cannot find good documentation anywhere with Cloudinary on how to do this. Is there already an answer for this?